# Unpacking first dimension of NumPy array into pyplot.plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, unpack

I have five sets of x,y data I'd like to plot in a single `plt.plot()` command by unwrapping the first dimension only of my array (of shape `(5,2,500)`. If I try:

```
plt.plot(*arr)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

but if I plot by sending the x,y pairs separately, it works. e.g. for three lines:

```
plt.plot(arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[1][0], arr[1][1], arr[2][0], arr[2][1])
```

How can I unpack the first dimension only into the argument list for `pt.plot`?

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete answer right now. So i add this here, maybe someone else can make a complete answer from it. This seems to do what you're looking for `plt.plot(arr[:,0,:].T, arr[:,1,:].T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plt.plot(*arr)
```

is equivalent to

```
plt.plot(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4])
```

That's why it does not work.

As @M4rtini wrote in their comment, you can do `plt.plot(arr[:,0,:].T, arr[:,1,:].T)`.

`plt.plot(X, Y)` creates a separate plot for each column in `X` and `Y`. Thus, `arr[:, 0]` and `arr[:, 1]` extract blocks of x and y coordinates, and `.T` transposes the blocks so that the first dimension goes into the columns.